# ORTools- use different solvers in routing problem

Tags: python-3.x, or-tools, cp-sat

I know in Integer Optimization problem, we can use different solver(CP-SAT or original-CP).In routing problem（tsp or other）how to use different solve problem.  I find this function(SolveModelWithSat) maybe can use different solver by the OR-Tools document,but I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are parameters that control what to use.
Please note that CP-SAT implementation does not support all features.

See: [This section in the parameter file](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/a0a56698ba8fd07b7f84aee4fc45d891a8cd9828/ortools/constraint_solver/routing_parameters.proto#L358)

Comment: thanks.But I have a question. Why set use_cp =True no result , use ortools demo